# Word for something that is likely significant?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

Is there an English word out there that describes something that is *likely* (probably) significant or important?

Meaning, there's a very good chance it's significant, remarkable, important, etc., but not necessarily; or rather it is not *definitely* significant?

Example:

> "*The input signal is likely significant if further analysis confirm the detected anomalies.*"

Comment: I think it could help if you provided a real-world example.

Comment: Are you looking for a single word? If so, you should add that tag.

Comment: Thanks for both suggestions; edits made!

Comment: For clarification, are you intending to use it in a specifically scientific context?   If so, then the word actually is 'significant' .  Statisticians say the results of a test are 'significant' if  they would occur by chance 1 time in 20.  Or 'highly significant' if the chance is 1 in 100.   Probably best to ask on a science forum for  correct usage.  IANA scientist.

Comment: Try "hopefully" in the sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**potential** (n, adj.)

> (n.)
>
> **Something which is possible, as opposed to actual**; capacity for
> growth, achievement, future development or use; resources able to be
> used or developed.
>
> (adj.)
>
> **Possible as opposed to actual;** having or showing the capacity to
> develop into something in the future; latent; prospective.
> (OED)

(However, you would have to be cautious in how you use it with an *input signal* because of the word's other meanings in physics.)

---

> The **potential** for *significant* reduction of operating expenses was
> also examined. [Sugar Bowl Ski Corporation of California et al.;
> *Draft environmental impact statement*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Draft_Environmental_Impact_Statement/TJBBAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=has%20potential%20and%20could%20be%20significant&dq=has%20potential%20and%20could%20be%20significant&printsec=frontcover) (1990)

> A procedure needs to be developed to identify any **potential**
> situations that could cause *significant* environmental impact. [T.
> Moore and R. Lakha; *Tolley's Handbook of Disaster and Emergency
> Management*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Tolley_s_Handbook_of_Disaster_and_Emerge/Br4JBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=has%20potential%20and%20could%20be%20significant&pg=PA245&printsec=frontcover) (2007)

Answer (score -1):

Possibly [indicative](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/indicative) would fit.

> adjective
>
> 1. showing, signifying, or pointing out; expressive or suggestive (usually followed by of):
>    *behavior indicative of mental disorde*r.

So, particular behaviour by a person might  say that it is highly likely that the person has a particular mental disorder, but doesn't prove it conclusively.

*Suggestive* might also fit.